# Cocoapods: Cannot use module 'xxx' as a type

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate Cocoapods to a customized search controller of mine.
 [Github-SKSearchController](https://github.com/JunsW/SKSearchController)

But the complier complained

[image]

I just imported it as usual.

[image]

What the problem?
The class name can't be the same as the module?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you are saying `import SKSearchController`. There is no module. It's not a framework. You just plop the SKSearchController file into your project and use the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set SKSearchController to a public or open class in your Github project.

Comment: I just forget the default internal can just be accessed inside module.